# A subset having volume implies the interior of that subset is same as volume of subset.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

Define volume as $\text{vol}(A) = \int _A 1$, and A has volume if this exists.

A couple questions similar to this has been asked, however, I (and everyone else) was unsure of their definition of volume. So, using the above definition show the following:

If $E'$ is a subset of $E^n$ has volume, then the interior of $E'$ has the same volume as $E'$.

I believe the best way to prove this is to prove that the boundary has volume of $0$ through a method making an $\epsilon$ containing the boundary arbitrarily small. Could someone help me prove this?

Useful Definition: Let $S$ be a subset of the metric space $E$. A point $p\in S$ is called an interior point of $S$ if there is an open ball in $E$ of center $p$ which is contatined in $S$. The set of interior points of $S$ is an open subset of $E$, called the interior, that contains all other open subsets of $E$ that are contained in $S$.

Comment: I am not well-familiar with non-Lebesgue integrals in $\Bbb R^n$. At least for the Lebesgue one the statement is not true: there are sets of positive volume with empty interior. Also, $n$-dimensional metric space does not mean anything.

Comment: to be more specific, see [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set)

Comment: Would you please provide links to those couple similar questions? What is "their" definition of volume, is it not equivalent to yours. How do you know that *everyone else* is unsure, when you didn't even clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to prove the following. Your definition of "volume" is Jordan measure: 
$$
\mbox{vol}(A) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \mathbb{1}_A,
$$
where we are taking the *Reimann* integral of the indicator function 
$$
\mathbb{1}_A(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \mbox{if } x \in A \\
0 & \mbox{if } x \notin A
\end{cases}
$$
of a bounded set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. It turns out that 
$$
A \mbox{ "has volume" (is Jordan measurable)} \iff \mbox{vol}(\partial A) = 0
$$
is a theorem, where 
\begin{align*}
\partial A &= \bar A \backslash A^\circ \mbox{ is the boundary of } A, \\
\bar A &= \mbox{closure of } A, \\
A^\circ &= \mbox{interior of } A.
\end{align*}
Hence if $A$ "has volume", $\mbox{vol}(A)$ exists and is squeezed by $\mbox{vol}(A^\circ) \leq \mbox{vol}(A) \leq \mbox{vol}(\bar A)$ since $A^\circ \subseteq A \subseteq \bar A$. If $\bar A$ "has volume", write $\bar A$ as the disjoint union $\bar A = \partial A \cup A^\circ$, and compute
$$
\mbox{vol}(\bar A) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \mathbb{1}_{\bar A} = \underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \mathbb{1}_{\partial A}}_{0} + \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \mathbb{1}_{A^\circ} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \mathbb{1}_{A^\circ} = \mbox{vol}(A^\circ).
$$
The step $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \mathbb{1}_{\partial A} = 0$ follows from the theorem under the hypothesis that $A$ "has volume".

By the "squeezed" inequality, we've computed $\mbox{vol}(A) = \mbox{vol}(A^\circ)$. Of course, we've made some extra assumptions by using $\bar A$, but these can be relaxed.

If this is indeed what you mean, we can discuss the proof of the theorem.

Comment: this seems like a good candidate for the "correct" interpretation